# (R) - Fill missing integer range by group with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am using R studio, mostly dplyr processing, where I have a df of users (A,B,C,...) and what day since their first visit they were active (1,2,3,...)

| user | day | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | T |
| A | 3 | T |
| B | 2 | T |
| B | 4 | T |

I would like to complete this list with all missing days - up to their current maximum value (so for user B until 4 and for user A until 3) - and value FALSE:

| user | day | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | T |
| A | 2 | F |
| A | 3 | T |
| B | 1 | F |
| B | 2 | T |
| B | 3 | F |
| B | 4 | T |

I've been googling and chewing on this for hours now. Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could group by 'user' and then get the sequence from `min` to `max` of 'day' in `complete` to expand the data while `fill`ing the 'active' column with `FALSE` (by default missing combinations are filled with `NA`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  complete(day = min(day):max(day), fill = list(active = FALSE)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  user    day active
  <chr> <int> <lgl> 
1 A         1 TRUE  
2 A         2 FALSE 
3 A         3 TRUE  
4 B         2 TRUE  
5 B         3 FALSE 
6 B         4 TRUE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(user = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), day = c(1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L), active = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dataframe of users and days for all users and all days and then join it to your existing dataframe then set the active column. Something like this:

```
fullDf <- data.frame("user" = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)), 
           "day" = rep(1:4, 2))

existingDf <- left_join(fullDf, existingDf, by = c("user", "day"))
existingDf$active <- ifelse(is.na(existingDf$active), FALSE, existingDf$active
```